# Python: How to Call a function in another file with a circular import

Tags: python, function, python-import

I am making a text-based floor game for learning purposes. I want all of the moving-around functions to be in a separate python file but I am having issues getting them to work together.

I have the main game called `floors.py` and the map file is `floormap.py`.

I can import and run functions from `floormap.py` inside of `floors.py` perfectly okay.

But I do not know how to return to the `floors.py`functions after running a `floormap.py` functions. Here is an example below. When I run this, I get the following error in terminal:

```
NameError: global name 'first_hall_1' is not defined
```

I did get this working using:

```
from floormap import first_hall_1
```

But I could find a way to get the functions to once again be called in the original file.

Floors.py:

```
import floormap

def first_hall_object():
    grab = raw_input("Enter Command > ")

    backward = ['back', 'Back', 'Backward', 'backward']

    if any (s in grab for s in backward): 
        first_hall_1()

def walkin_hall():
    print "whatever"
```

floormap.py:

```
import floors 

def first_hall_1():
    print "You are in front of the door again. It is locked."
    walkin_hall()
```

Comment: Try to reorganize your code so that the two modules don't depend on each other like that. Eg, make it so floors.py imports floormap and calls floormap functions, but _don't_ have floormap.py also importing floors and calling floors functions. Circular imports are legal, but they can lead to a world of pain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to qualify `first_hall_1` with the module name `floormap`.

```
def first_hall_object():
    grab = raw_input("Enter Command > ")

    backward = ['back', 'Back', 'Backward', 'backward']

    if any (s in grab for s in backward): 
        floormap.first_hall_1()  # <-----
```

Same for the `walkin_hall()` call:

```
def first_hall_1():
    print "You are in front of the door again. It is locked."
    floors.walkin_hall()
```

Comment: The OP is making circular imports, which won't work with the `from ... import ...` syntax (not all the time, anyway). The `walkin_hall()` call in `floormap.py` needs to be `floors.walkin_hall()`

Comment: @Blckknght, Thank you for pointing that out. I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: 'AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'first_hall_1'

Comment: I think I am doing something seriously wrong. I am still getting the same attribute error even with the new addition. Does it matter that the "walkin_hall" function is below the "first_hall_object" function. Since the functions always go up.

UPDATE: Just tried moving up walkin_hall above the other function. No effect.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xv4epezfn6azjxu/ved%20.mp4?dl=0

I cannot get it to work even though I have everything typed correctly.

Comment: @HenFish, As Blckknght pointed, there are circular imports. (which prevent full import is done before the `first_hall_1` call) Try to extract `first_hall_object()` call out into another module (like `main.py` I did).

Comment: @falsetru Okay thank you so much!! Sorry for being such a bother. I really appreciate the help!